# how to show two value in the same field

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import DatePicker from 'material-ui/DatePicker';
class Balaa extends Component {
  state = {
   first:'',
   second:'',
  }
  handleChangeFirstEventDate = (event, date) => {
    this.setState({
      first: date,
    });
  }
  handleChangeSecondDate = (event, date) => {
    this.setState({
      second: date,
    });
  }
  render() {
    const { value } = this.state
    <label> First Date </label>
    <DatePicker
       fullWidth={true}
       name='firstdate'
       placeholder='YYYY-MM-DD'
       value={this.state.first}
       onChange={this.handleChangeFirstEventDate}
    />
    <label> Second Date </label>
    <DatePicker
       fullWidth={true}
       name='second'
       placeholder='YYYY-MM-DD'
       value={this.state.second}
       onChange={this.handleChangeSecondDate}
    />
    <label> Multiple Date </label>
    <DatePicker
       fullWidth={true}
       name='multipledate'
       placeholder='YYYY-MM-DD'
       value={...} //show the first and second date together
       disabled />
  }
}
export default Balaa
```

The basic idea is. I want a field that can display the first and second date. At the beginning, I use TestField to show, but I found the field displed "Mon Nov 11 2017". I want it to be xxxx-xx-xx format. The field only does display feature. The value of this field can not be changed. So I set disabled to not allow the user to change the value. For example, I choose the first is 2017-11-27 and the second is 2017-11-28. I want the field displays 2017-11-27;2017-11-28. I just start learning to react.

Comment: If you want customized designs, you should create your own component. Material UI's components are gonna work the way they are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [TextField](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/text-field) and format the values as you wish:

```
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField'

<TextField
  disabled
  value={`${this.state.first},${this.state.second}`}
/>
```

To format the values you can use [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/) as:

`moment(this.state.first).format('YYYY-MM-DD')`.

So final result would be:

```
const formatDate = (date) => moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD')

<TextField
  disabled
  value={`${formatDate(this.state.first)},${formatDate(this.state.second)}`}
/>
```

Comment: and he's got to get rid of the `DatePicker` component as well, ryt ? I think giving `display: none` to `textFieldStyle` prop will suffice

Comment: That was my suggestion :) Since it's a `readOnly` field I don't see why use `DatePicker`

Comment: do I need to import for the momentjs? Or npm install thing?

Comment: When I do npm start, it shows moment is not define. We use node.js. And it's JSX

Comment: @JeffYan You need to install `moment` as well.

Comment: @mersocarlin, yea, I figure it out. It works, however it shows 02017-11-11;02017-11-12. There is "0" at frond of each date.

Comment: @JeffYan sure thing. I added an extra `Y` in the date mask. I already updated my answer :)

Comment: At the beginning, we didn't select any date. It shows "Invalid date;Invalid date". I mean if I only choose the first date, I want "2011-11-11" not the "2011-11-11; Invalid date"

Comment: @JeffYan this means you need an extra check in `format` function and render an empty text instead :)